# Returning the actual index value of max & min values from a Pandas Dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How do I print/return the index of a particular value?

```
movies_per_year = pd.DataFrame(movies_per_year)
movies_per_year.columns = ["count"]
print(movies_per_year)

        count
year       
1891      1
1893      1
1894      2
1895      2
1896      2
1898      5
```

Here, my index is the **year**. I want to *return all the indexes where count is 1*. Furthermore **movies_per_year.max()** returns **5**. So, it should return **1898**.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17071908/3914029

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Comment: I tried it at first place, it didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`np.where()` - returns positional indices of the elements that satisfy the given condition:

```
In [31]: np.where(df['count'] == 1)[0]
Out[31]: array([0, 1], dtype=int64)
```

or

```
In [35]: np.nonzero(df['count'] == 1)
Out[35]: (array([0, 1], dtype=int64),)
```

if you need real index values (labels) instead of their positions:

```
In [40]: df.index[df['count'] == 1]
Out[40]: Int64Index([1891, 1893], dtype='int64', name='year')
```

to find an index of a maximum element:

```
In [32]: df['count'].idxmax()
Out[32]: 1898
```

Comment: Great! I just have one doubt, how do I print all the years that have count 1. For example, it should print 1891 and 1893.

Comment: try this to print all years that have count 1 `df.index[df['count'] == 1].tolist()` -- ignore this i see the answer was edited already to include it.

Comment: @HamzaHaider, yes, we can use `Index.tolist()` method to convert index to Vanilla Python list. Thank you!